# How to edit preferences when in fullscreen mode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, hotkeys, fullscreen

In VLC media player, I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open up the preferences dialog when in fullscreen mode, but has no effect. The same goes for opening the codec information via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Does anyone know how to bring them up when in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried this on multiple Windows computers, the preferences dialog can only be opened in non-fullscreen mode.